# Counting the number of rows in MySQL table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to select and echo data

```
Select maintable.movie_title, group_concat(genres.genres_name) AS genres_name
FROM maintable
JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)
GROUP BY maintable.tmdb_id,maintable.movie_title
HAVING find_in_set('$category1', genres_name) AND find_in_set('$category2', genres_name)

 LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start
 // Then fire it up
 $stmt->execute();

 // Pick up the result as an array
 $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I have 2 tables

1.) `maintable`

2.) `genres` table

Both tables are linked to each other using `tmdb_id`

(Please do not ask to show, what I tried. Trust me, it will make the question more confusing)

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation to get a count of the matching rows.  Unfortunately, your query is in a mess, so I can't give a formal answer.  You are grouping by `tmdb_id` but you select `movie_title`, a non aggregate column.  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Fixed the question @TimBiegeleisen I just forgot to include that. My real code is 5x bigger than this, but i put only required code

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

if you need also  the count of   $totalrows, which have $category1 and $category2
 You should use a where in clause

```
  Select maintable.movie_title, group_concat(genres.genres_name) AS genres_name, count(*) as total_rows
  FROM maintable
  JOIN genres USING (tmdb_id)
  where genres.genres_name in ('$category1', '$category2' )
  GROUP BY maintable.tmdb_id, maintable.movie_title

   LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start
```

if you need  only tital_rows  you could select only this value (and use $totalrows = $result->fetchColumn(); ) or in this fecth the column 2  using

```
 $totalrows = $result->fetchColumn(2);
```

or using fetchAll

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $key=>$row){

  echo $row['total_rows']  ;

}
```

Comment: I want to calculate total rows before `$limit` variable. So i can give a value to it

Comment: @JoshPoor   what do you mean ? .. i don't understand  .. update your question add  a  proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: `$totalrows = $result->fetchColumn(); ` how to calculate it here?

Comment: I mean how to calculate total rows and transfer the value of it to a variable?

Comment: Bro the answer is `4316410442449`

Comment: I don't know your data .. i don't know if this result is right or worng  .. if is worng  ... then as required  before update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on array in `